# Continue next Observable onError

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have sequence of tasks to be completed, if any of them throws exception would like to continue with next task.

But with this implementation, if first REST calls fail it throws onError in subscriber.

Wondering what is best operator to use or I need to call some other function to make it resume on exception.

```
private void logout() {
    // Observable from Retrofit to make logout service call
    requestLogout()
            .doOnNext(o -> {
                clearNotifications();
            })
            .doOnNext(o -> {
                unregisterGcm();
            })
            .doOnNext(o -> {
                clearLocalData();
            })
            .doOnNext(o -> {
                // clear all jobs
                mJobManager.clear();
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    // no op
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    mView.navigateToLogin();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Object o) {
                    mView.navigateToLogin();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Maybe [`onErrorResumeNext`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to re-subscribe use `Observable.retry()`:

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.retry().subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
 // rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found way to execute all the Observables even if one of them have error. But this does not preserve order.

I am still looking for way where order is preserved and on error it should continue to next observable.

```
Observable.mergeDelayError(requestLogout(),
            clearNotifications(),
            unregisterGcm(),
            clearLocalData(),
            clearJobs())
            .first()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onCompleted() {
                               // no op
                           }

                           @Override
                           public void onError(Throwable e) {
                               mView.navigateToLogin();
                           }

                           @Override
                           public void onNext(Object o) {
                               mView.navigateToLogin();
                           }
                       }
            );
```